# What are the Guardian of Earth's tasks in Dragon Ball series?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

In case the question is not very clear, What I want to know is:

- What Dende or Kami must do as the Guardian of Earth?
- Do they have to *protect* human being from *evil*?
- Do they have to create the dragon balls?
- Do they have to hear and grant (if appropriate) any humans wish
  (as the comment said they referenced as God)?
- Do they have to watch over every activity that people on earth do?
- If they don't have to create dragon balls, do they have to be from Namek?
- Aside from people safety, in what problems they may or must help humans 
  for fulfilling their job as Guardian of Earth?

Basically, the question is what are their tasks as the Guardian of Earth?

Comment: Because of the dragon balls, you know..

Comment: Do you mean what in the Dragonball universe is refered as god on earth?

Comment: Well, I don't think the question is *very* clear. I think you should make it more clear by editing in what exactly you want to know about that, and why it may be important.

Comment: @Hakase updated. added some details.

Comment: Great! Next time just edit it to make it look like it was the initial version, without "edited" or "updated", that's just unnecessary as you can always [see each revision in post history](http://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/29980/revisions).

Comment: Try to ask one question per post. I see at least 2 questions here: "What Dende or Kami must do as the guardian of earth?" and "Do they have to be from Namek?". I think I can pick out one or two more distinct questions from your list.

Comment: Yep, I edited the question title. The first one is what I want to know so badly. Anyway, thanks for constructive comment. And sorry if my english is not so nice (not my main language).

Comment: @MasBagol: To make sure that you get satisfactory answer for your questions, it's best to split them up into multiple questions, if they are not closely related. Otherwise, people will just post an answer to one of those questions without addressing others. For example, "do they have to be from Namek?" worth its own question and should be post separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As is mentioned on the [wikia](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Guardian) site,

> Guardian (神様, Kami-sama; lit. "God") is the title given to the individual protectors of planets in the Dragon Ball series.
>
> Despite their names, the Guardians' role is closer to that of an overseer.

As the Guardian of Earth (I will be using GE as an abbreviation), Kami or Dende have to protect the human beings from evil. A few examples being

- Kami training Goku during the Piccolo Jr. Saga.
- Kami training the other Z Warriors during the Saiyan Saga.
- > Kami and Mr. Popo spreading the Sacred Water throughout the entire world using the Seven Air Currents located inside Kami's Lookout in order to cure the Earthlings from the effects of Garlic Jr.'s Black Water Mist.

To expand a bit more on their job,

> Guardians have an indirect reporting relationship to one of the Kais (in the case of the Guardian of Earth, this is King Kai).
>
> Another way of looking at this is that Guardians are more supervisors than they are managers.
>
> They have many of the powers associated with Gods, including the ability to see and sense events around the world, to travel to and guide souls to Other World, and to be a general protector of the people.

This concludes the tasks of the GE.

Now to answer your other questions,

- The GE doesn't necessarily have to be from Namek. The reference being that

  - Kami was the first Namekian GE.
  - Kami asks Goku to replace him as the GE after the World Martial Arts Tournament in Piccolo Jr. Saga.
- As the GE doesn't have to be Namekian, they don't have to create the dragon balls.
- They do grant human wishes if they are appropriate. An example being when he gave a new life to Shenron on Goku's demand after he was destroyed by King Piccolo.

I believe this answers all your questions...

Comment: well much better than mine that is clear +1

Comment: @xerido Thanks. As a matter of fact, your answer is good too...

Answer (score 4):

In the anime and the manga the guardian of earth functions are more of a supervisors than actual defender (had to search up for this).

They normaly report the state of the earth to one of the Kais. They don't directly mend with human activities and are more concerned with other tasks, like mantaining the varius portals that exist where they live.

Now to the rest of the questions regarding namekians:

- No they don't have to be namekian, Kami was the first namekian Guardian, before he was named kami he was the nameless namekian. to become kami ( or the guardian), he had to cast out all the evil inside him that is what becomes piccolo.
- They don't create the dragonballs, they didn't existed until kami came to earth, because dragonballs are a namekian creation of a specific cast.
- Dende became the new guardian after kami because kami fused with piccolo jr and the dragon balls stoped to work, dende is of the special cast of namekians that can create dragonballs, he even empowered them after restoring them making him able to grant two wishes instead of one

Source: http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Guardian